# How to list child pages on link-based parent item in WordPress menu

Tags: wordpress, list, menu, children

My menu is formed by a custom link as parent and inside it a set of child pages. I want to get all its children but all I find is how to list child pages by parent id

Answer (score 0):

To get all the children related to a particular parent on one of it's child pages, you could do the following

```
global $post;
//If the page has children - print the list
if(wp_get_post_parent_id( $post->ID ))
{
    $args = array(
            'child_of' => wp_get_post_parent_id( $post->ID ),
            'title_li' => ''
    );
    wp_list_pages($args); 
}
```

Comment: When I execute this snippet it returns nothing because I have not parent page, the parent is a "custom link" which has all the children pages underneath